# Object comparison giving fatal error

Tags: php

I was given a question to answer without executing.

```
class Foo {
    public $x;
}
$a = new Foo();
$b = new Foo();
$a->x = $b;
$b->x = $a;

print_r($a == $b);
```

I thought this should print 1 but when i executed it gave a fatal error.

```
Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? on line 13
```

Can anyone explain why i am getting this error ?

Comment: You can use `===` to compare references

Comment: The error prevents the compiler having to go down the never ending loop rabbit hole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way PHP compares objects.

When you compare objects with `==`, PHP will look at each property of each object (and nested objects, in case some properties contain other objects), and compare them. The objects would be considered equal if all properties are equal.

In this specific case, you're placing the objects within each others' properties, causing the comparison engine to loop (`$a->b->a->b->a->b->...`), which throws an error.

Comment: Right..Very well explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP tries to find out if the objects are equal, not if the references are equal. To evaluate this the object is travered completely. This traversal includes the references pointing to other objects. So you implemented an endless loop...